# Can you solve current version of Quadratic reciprocity from Gauss version?

Tags: number-theory

Can you solve [current version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Legendre.27s_version_of_quadratic_reciprocity)( after: "He notes that these can be combined") of Quadratic reciprocity from [Gauss version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Gauss.27s_version)?
I have tried it but I have problem to understand especially if $ q \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \Rightarrow  (\frac{p}{q}) =1 \Leftrightarrow (\frac{-p}{q}) =1$.
I understand that if $ q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$(2) then by using Euler's criterion you get $(\frac{p}{q}) =1$, but don't know how you get  $(\frac{q}{p}) =1$(1). But is this(1) goal if you assume (2)?

Comment: What does "current version" mean?

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: I made link to the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gauss' version:

(1) Suppose $q\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.  Then $x^2\equiv p\pmod{q}$ is solvable if and only if $x^2\equiv q\pmod{p}$ is solvable.  Using Legendre symbols, this means exactly $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$.

(2) Suppose $q\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.  Then Then $x^2\equiv p\pmod{q}$ is solvable if and only if $x^2\equiv -q\pmod{p}$ is solvable.  Using Legendre symbols, this means exactly $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{-q}{p}\right)$.

We may write $\left(\frac{-q}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$.  But by the first supplement to QR, $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$.

Hence, if $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$ or $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=1=(-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}$.

If instead $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)$ or $\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=-1=(-1)^{\frac{(p-1)(q-1)}{4}}$.

Comment: @ vadim123: I would like to ask that how this assumption that $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is used in (1) amd same thing in (2): How you use your assumption $q \equiv 3  \pmod 4$ in your (2) solution. Do you assume that when $q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then if p is QR iff q is QR, then also $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: The assumptions on $q$ are part of Gauss' version of the theorem; it comes in two parts which I label (1) and (2).  See the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Gauss.27s_version) you provided.

Comment: Yes, I see. But just for clarification do you agree that it seems that Gauss does not show why $(\frac{p}{q})=(\frac{-q}{p})$ if $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$? Can it be shown easily or is it difficult? I don't get why this(2) holds?

Comment: The proof of Gauss' version does not appear in Wikipedia, only the statement.  That statement was the starting point for my above calculation, and was the basis of your question.